# cassandra-web installation fails with: cannot load such file -- 2.5/lz4ruby.so

Tags: ruby, cassandra, datastax

I am installing `Cassanrda-web`, but when i run the command "`cassandra-web --hosts '127.0.0.1' --port '9042'`" it gives me the error, actuary i have installed `cassandra` with `datastax` and there was no username and password set, but even when i have tested this command with `username and password` as empty then same error occurred. here is the error log.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cassandra-web:23:in `<main>'
     10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cassandra-web:23:in `load'
      9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/cassandra-web-0.4.0/bin/cassandra-web:104:in `<top (required)>'
      8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/cassandra-web-0.4.0/bin/cassandra-web:78:in `run'
      7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/cassandra-driver-3.2.3/lib/cassandra.rb:296:in `cluster'
      6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/cassandra-driver-3.2.3/lib/cassandra.rb:306:in `cluster_async'
      5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/cassandra-driver-3.2.3/lib/cassandra.rb:464:in `validate_and_massage_options'
      4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/cassandra-driver-3.2.3/lib/cassandra.rb:464:in `new'
      3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/cassandra-driver-3.2.3/lib/cassandra/compression/compressors/lz4.rb:42:in `initialize'
      2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/cassandra-driver-3.2.3/lib/cassandra/compression/compressors/lz4.rb:42:in `require'
      1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/lz4-ruby-0.3.3/lib/lz4-ruby.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/gems/lz4-ruby-0.3.3/lib/lz4-ruby.rb:4:in `require': LZ4 support requires the "lz4-ruby" gem: cannot load such file -- 2.5/lz4ruby.so (LoadError)
```

Comment: `gem install lz4-ruby`

Comment: @anothermh, i have installed lz4-ruby and return message  "1 gem installed"
But still same error.

Comment: @KashifSohail did you get this error solved?